# Using JSTL to display a table on a webpage

Tags: html, sql, jsp, jstl

So I've set up some SQL tables and just to test and get my head around the data so I can test it. 
So I use:

```
SELECT * From Customer
</sql:query>
```

Now I want to take "result" and print it out the whole table!
preferably using the:

```
<c: out />
```

Any ideas or better ways?

Comment: Do the query in a servlet, put the results of the query in a request attribute and forward from the servlet to a JSP.

Comment: How would you do this? Quite new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

Do the query in a servlet not a JSP. For example, one way would be to put the results of the query in a request attribute and forward from the servlet to a JSP.

In servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("queryresults", queryresults);
request.getRequestDispatcher("somejsp.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${queryresults}" var="row">
        <tr>
            <td>${row.field1}</td>
            <td>${row.field2}</td>
            <td>${row.field3}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

See also [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)